# error: ‘usb_serial_probe’ undeclared, linux 3.10 in device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to compile a Linux drived for USB-to-Serial device and getting error

```
 /root/moxa_usb_to_serial/mxu11x0/driver/mxu11x0.c:307: error: ‘usb_serial_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 /root/moxa_usb_to_serial/mxu11x0/driver/mxu11x0.c:308: error: ‘usb_serial_disconnect’ undeclared here (not in a function)
```

I have linux

```
 Linux host 3.10.33-rt32.34.el6rt.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed May 28 09:57:12 CEST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The manufacturer of driver actually warns that above 3.4 driver might not be compartible. However driver itself is rather small and I believe I can make some trivial fixes. How this can be solved?

Comment: Is CONFIG_USB_SERIAL defined in your .config file?  Also check /proc/kallsyms for your usb_* functions available in your kernel.  Those functions are part of usb-serial.c: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/serial/usb-serial.c#L697

Comment: Did you solve in anyway? Did moxa provided you an update driver?

Comment: @ceztko, write to their support. They will send you what they have at the moment. I believe there is also a forum where you can seek for newer drivers. It is in Russian though. http://www.moxa.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/478-uport-1110-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80/page__st__120

Answer (score 5):

> The manufacturer of driver actually warns that above 3.4 driver might not be compartible.

A quick check of one symbol indicates that this aspect of the kernel USB serial interface has changed.  In 3.10 **usb_serial_probe()** was made static (see its [3.10 cross reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.10;i=usb_serial_probe)), so it's no longer part of the kernel USB interface.  There's no need to go looking for the "proper" header file to include.
Your presumption about making *"some trivial fixes"* may be hasty.

You need to get the 3.4 Linux source tree and find examples of the USB serial interface.
[Here's a list of the 3.4 drivers that use **usb_serial_probe()**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.4&i=usb_serial_probe).
You need to find a 3.4 driver that resembles the driver that you're trying to port, e.g. uses **usb_serial_probe()** and **usb_serial_disconnect()** such as [**usb/serial/generic.c**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/serial/generic.c?v=3.4).
Then find that version of the driver in the 3.10 source, and see how that driver has evolved since 3.4 (use `diff` or `sdiff`).
Those changes will be a guide to what has to be modified in your driver.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I belive you summed it up pretty well.

Answer (score -1):

I have that symbols defined in a file called usb-serial.h, in a driver for quite another interface. But it gives me the impression you are not including the right header files for the compilation of your driver.

So, I'd suggest you do a search in all .h files in your driver directory, and look for a function called usb_serial_probe. If you find it, check if you are correctly adding the file in your compile command.

Are you using a manufacturer-provided Makefile?